# tf.random.shuffle not giving reproducible results even when seed is specified

Tags: tensorflow

There's an argument in that function seed=something. Even when I set its value, the shuffle give random results. I want the same results.

```
tf.random.suffle(tf.range(5), seed=5)
```

Comment: What the heck is the point of seed argument if it doesn't do anything?

Comment: from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/set_random_seed) it looks like there's two seeds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to reproduce shuffle results, use (on TF 2.0 beta) the following

```py
tf.random.set_seed(5)
tf.random.shuffle(tf.range(5))
<tf.Tensor: id=35, shape=(5,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([0, 4, 1, 3, 2], dtype=int32)>
tf.random.set_seed(5)
tf.random.shuffle(tf.range(5))
<tf.Tensor: id=41, shape=(5,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([0, 4, 1, 3, 2], dtype=int32)>
tf.random.set_seed(5)
tf.random.shuffle(tf.range(5))
<tf.Tensor: id=47, shape=(5,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([0, 4, 1, 3, 2], dtype=int32)>
```

About the seed you have used, it indeed fails to reproduce results, tested in TF 2.0 beta

In TF 1.x I believe the right functions is `tf.random.set_random_seed`

From the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/set_random_seed), I can see there are op level seed, and graph level seed. You are setting the op level, which is not enough - setting the graph level seed with the function in the code above solves this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this question. It seems like there is now a `tf.random.experimental.stateless_shuffle` that should give reproducible results.

To get random seeds, you can use `tf.random.Generator`.